# Firebase security rules to check array length

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

Is it possible to enforce the votes array to have exactly 5 entries?

newData.child('votes').val().length === 5) doesn't seem to work as the length property only works with strings. Here is my data:

```
votes
   $voteID
     page:"12345"
     user: "facebook:1234567"
     votes: {
       -K3M2kpTEtXRk-sHV6FO: true
       -K3M2kp_5vZDCZKUke2M: true
       -K3M2kpe7l22mYA1dc6D: true
       -K3M2kqhpgehSSUAcFLl: true
       -K3M2krABl2tU-cekpDA: true
    }
```

Is it possible at all to enforce this validation ?

Comment: Just came to my mind it might be better replacing "votes" with "vote1", "vote2" up to "vote5". This way I will be able to do further validation.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
"!newData.hasChild('X')"
```

where `X` is the length you want `+1`

and for further validation like you specified you can always do

```
"$index" : { 
   ".validate" : "... some validation .. "
}
```

so my answer does not limit you in any way and can support to any array limit